# Find count of distinct values between two same values in a csv file using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, bigdata

Im working on pyspark to deal with big CSV files more than 50gb.
Now I need to find the number of distinct values between two references to the same value.
for example,

```
input dataframe:
+----+
|col1|
+----+
|   a|
|   b|
|   c|
|   c| 
|   a|   
|   b|
|   a|     
+----+


output dataframe:
+----+-----+
|col1|col2 |
+----+-----+
|   a| null|
|   b| null|
|   c| null|
|   c|    0| 
|   a|    2|
|   b|    2|   
|   a|    1| 
+----+-----+
```

I'm struggling with this for past one week. Tried window functions and many things in spark. But couldn't get anything. It would be a great help if someone knows how to fix this. Thank you.

Comment if you need any clarification in the question.

Comment: so for example there is "a" on row 1 in col1 and next "a" on row 5 - from where the 2 in col2 row 5 happened? (shouldn't it be 3?)

Comment: Hello so RDD's countByKey will not work in your case?

Comment: @piotr reszke 2 is the count of distinct values between  a and a

Comment: @Alexandros Biratsis but i need count between two values in every row. not for entire data frame

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520830/pyspark-dataframe-get-previous-row-that-meets-a-condition

Answer (score 0):

I am providing solution, with some assumptions.

Assuming, previous reference can be found in max of previous 'n' rows. If 'n' is reasonable less value, i think this is good solution.

I assumed you can find the previous reference in 5 rows.

```
def get_distincts(list, current_value):
    cnt = {}
    flag = False
    for i in list:
        if current_value == i :
            flag = True
            break
        else:
            cnt[i] = "some_value"

    if flag:
        return len(cnt)
    else:
        return None

get_distincts_udf = udf(get_distincts, IntegerType())
```

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([["a"],["b"],["c"],["c"],["a"],["b"],["a"]]).toDF("col1")
#You can replace this, if you have some unique id column 
df = df.withColumn("seq_id", monotonically_increasing_id()) 

window = Window.orderBy("seq_id")
df = df.withColumn("list", array([lag(col("col1"),i, None).over(window) for i in range(1,6) ]))

df = df.withColumn("col2", get_distincts_udf(col('list'), col('col1'))).drop('seq_id','list')
df.show()
```

which results

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   a|null|
|   b|null|
|   c|null|
|   c|   0|
|   a|   2|
|   b|   2|
|   a|   1|
+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach:

1. add a monotonically_increasing column `id` to keep track the order of rows
2. find `prev_id` for each `col1` and save the result to a new df
3. for the new DF (alias 'd1'), make a `LEFT JOIN` to the DF itself (alias 'd2') with a condition `(d2.id > d1.prev_id) & (d2.id < d1.id)`
4. then groupby(`'d1.col1'`, `'d1.id'`) and aggregate on the countDistinct(`'d2.col1'`)

The code based on the above logic and your sample data is shown below:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([ (i,) for i in list("abccaba")], ["col1"])

# create a WinSpec partitioned by col1 so that we can find the prev_id
win = Window.partitionBy('col1').orderBy('id')

# set up id and prev_id
df11 = df1.withColumn('id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())\
          .withColumn('prev_id', F.lag('id').over(win))

# check the newly added columns
df11.sort('id').show()
# +----+---+-------+
# |col1| id|prev_id|
# +----+---+-------+
# |   a|  0|   null|
# |   b|  1|   null|
# |   c|  2|   null|
# |   c|  3|      2|
# |   a|  4|      0|
# |   b|  5|      1|
# |   a|  6|      4|
# +----+---+-------+

# let's cache the new dataframe
df11.persist()

# do a self-join on id and prev_id and then do the aggregation
df12 = df11.alias('d1') \
           .join(df11.alias('d2')
               , (F.col('d2.id') > F.col('d1.prev_id')) & (F.col('d2.id') < F.col('d1.id')), how='left') \
           .select('d1.col1', 'd1.id', F.col('d2.col1').alias('ids')) \
           .groupBy('col1','id') \
           .agg(F.countDistinct('ids').alias('distinct_values'))

# display the result
df12.sort('id').show()
# +----+---+---------------+
# |col1| id|distinct_values|
# +----+---+---------------+
# |   a|  0|              0|
# |   b|  1|              0|
# |   c|  2|              0|
# |   c|  3|              0|
# |   a|  4|              2|
# |   b|  5|              2| 
# |   a|  6|              1|
# +----+---+---------------+

# release the cached df11
df11.unpersist()
```

**Note** you will need to keep this `id` column to sort rows, otherwise your resulting rows will be totally messed up each time you collect them.

Answer (score 0):

```
reuse_distance = []

block_dict = {}
stack_dict = {}
counter_reuse = 0
counter_stack = 0
reuse_list = []
```

Here block is nothing but the characters you want to read and search from csv

```
stack_list = []
        stack_dist = -1
        reuse_dist = -1
        if block in block_dict:
            reuse_dist = counter_reuse - block_dict[block]-1
            block_dict[block] = counter_reuse
            counter_reuse += 1
            stack_dist_ind= stack_list.index(block)

            stack_dist = counter_stack -stack_dist_ind - 1
            del stack_list[stack_dist_ind]
            stack_list.append(block)

        else:
            block_dict[block] = counter_reuse
            counter_reuse += 1
            counter_stack += 1
            stack_list.append(block)

        reuse_distance_2.append([block, stack_dist, reuse_dist])
```